# SQL code to ignore last 2 digits

Tags: mysql, sql, return

`user1` is the login in my system. `user1-1` is same person but with a different login.

**Question :**
SQL code to find any user who has a `dash` and a `number` in the end and simply ignore it.

(i.e) If you see `user1-1`, ignore the `-1` and return `user1`

Answer (score 2):

This way:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '-', 1) FROM table
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution in MySQL.

Comment: after '-' u have specifed 1 then why its not returning first character after hyphen

Comment: how can we do this in ms sql sever

Comment: This question is to solve a different problem. As your problem is different it would have to be in another question in order to the others find the answer easily when looking for it. For your case, you'd need it like: LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '-', -1),1) . The value -1 would be to take the right side of the delimiter and the LEFT function would be to take the left most character.

Comment: SUBSTRING_INDEX works in mysql but i an writting queries in MS SQL

Comment: Yes, this function is just for mysql. THis question was tagged to mysql before. But in SQL server it is gonna have to be some solution with charindex.

Answer (score 1):

This might hepls you

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (username,1 , len(username)-2 ) 
FROM user
```

or
try this for all rows including "-"(user-2) and other like(user)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (username,1 , len(username)-2 ) 
FROM  user
    where username like '%-%'

union all
    select top 1 username from user
    group by username
    having len(username)=(select min(len(username)) from user)
```

### gives total rows with 'user'

Mark this as answer or vote if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use the `REPLACE` function

```
SELECT REPLACE(username,'-1','')
FROM logintable
```

Comment: i dont want to use where clause.